# Problema con ng-recaptcha y Angular 6 con el comando ng build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, recaptcha

Actualmente estoy implementando [ng-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha) en mi proyecto Angular 6, implementando tal como en la documentación oficial.

Todo funciona bien con el reCaptcha V2 al estar desarrollando pero al momento de correr el ng build me marca el error:

> ERROR in : Unexpected value 'RecaptchaCommonModule in /node_modules/ng-recaptcha/recaptcha/recaptcha-common.module.js' imported by the module 'RecaptchaModule in node_modules/ng-recaptcha/recaptcha/recaptcha.module.d.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
>
> ERROR in : Unexpected value 'RecaptchaCommonModule. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

He buscado por todos lados y no encuentro algún caso igual.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
....
import { RecaptchaModule } from 'ng-recaptcha';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RecaptchaModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my-component.html

```
...
<re-captcha (resolved)="resolved($event)" siteKey="MY-KEY"></re-captcha>
...
```

my-component.ts

```
...
 resolved(captchaResponse: string) {
    this.modelo.token_captcha = captchaResponse;
    this.http.post('MY BACKEND', JSON.stringify({
      token_captcha: this.modelo.token_captcha
    }), {
      }).subscribe(res => {
        if (res['Error']) {
          this.captcha_valido = false;
        }
        else {
          this.captcha_valido = true;
        }
      });
  }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "buzon",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.53",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.3.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.8.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar el porqué de este error para solucionarlo.

Comment: Es posible que el fichero descargado por npm esté corrupto, yo probaría a borrar el directorio node_modules del proyecto y ejecutar `npm install` para descargarlos de nuevo

Comment: Funcionó de maravilla bro, ya compila sin problemas, gracias.

Comment: @PabloLozano sera conveniente que pongas tu comentario como respuesta para cerrar esta pregunta? Veo que tiene muchas vistas

Answer (score 0):

Luego de ejecutar un "ng build --prod", tenía este error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-recaptcha/fesm5/ng-recaptcha.js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
```

Para solucionarlo, en el archivo "angular.json" cambié el valor de ""buildOptimizer": true" a ""buildOptimizer": false".

Espero te sirva.

Ambiente:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.0
@angular/platform-server          6.1.10
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               0.6.0
@schematics/update                0.6.0
rxjs                              6.1.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el fichero descargado por npm esté corrupto, yo probaría a borrar el directorio node_modules del proyecto y ejecutar npm install para descargarlos de nuevo